# pyttsx: stop recording once started

Tags: python, pyttsx

I found a fork of `pyttsx` that lets you record. https://github.com/hick/pyttsx/tree/master/pyttsx

Here is my code:

```
engine =pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) #change index to change voices
engine.rec('test this out','test.wav')
```

The problem is... I can't open the file without closing the shell. But I need to run more code ... such as encode to mp3.

I have already tried `engine.stop()`. And I looked through here: https://github.com/hick/pyttsx/blob/master/pyttsx/engine.py ...

Comment: you can open a new terminal or window.

Answer (score 0):

Use **pyttsx3** instead of pyttsx:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Nice to meet you')
engine.runAndWait()
```